# iOS Chrome - cancelling momentum scroll prevents `touchstart` handlers from firing until you tap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

If you "flick" scroll in iOS Chrome, and then cancel the scroll by touching the screen, then you tap something that has a `touchstart` handler bound to it, it will not fire. It only fires if you've tapped the screen again after cancelling the scroll.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/nth-chile/pen/JEBLwo)

```
var $container = $('#container');
var $box = $('#box');
var toggle = true;

$box.on('touchstart', function() {
  if (toggle)
    $box.css('background-color', 'pink');
  else
    $box.css('background-color', 'skyblue');
  toggle = !toggle;
});
```

Any insight as to why this is happening?